# Shogun windows msvc 2015 build fail on Eigen including pthread.h

Tags: c++, eigen3, shogun

I'm trying to build shogun 6.1.3 on windows with msvc 2015 using cmake.
Here is the log of the configuration generated by cmake:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
Using system's malloc
Could NOT find GDB (missing: GDB_COMMAND GDB_VERSION) 
dir='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/src'
dir='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src'
dir='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/src/gpl'
Could NOT find CxaDemangle (missing: HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE) 
Could NOT find CxaDemangle (missing: HAVE_CXA_DEMANGLE) 
Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "3.1.2")
Could NOT find OPENCL (missing: OPENCL_LIBRARY OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ViennaCL (missing: VIENNACL_INCLUDE_DIR VIENNACL_ENCODED_VERSION OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS OpenCL_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least version "1.5.0")
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find TFLogger (missing: TFLogger_DIR)
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
LAPACK requires BLAS
Could NOT find GLPK (missing: GLPK_LIBRARY GLPK_INCLUDE_DIR GLPK_PROPER_VERSION_FOUND) 
Could NOT find CPLEX (missing: CPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find MOSEK (missing: MOSEK_DIR MOSEK_INCLUDE_DIR MOSEK_LIBRARY MOSEK_LIBRARIES) 
Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find JSON (missing: JSON_INCLUDE_DIR JSON_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "0.11")
Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_INCLUDE_DIR LIBLZMA_LIBRARY LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET) 
Could NOT find SNAPPY (missing: SNAPPY_LIBRARIES SNAPPY_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Lzo includes and libraries NOT found. 
Could NOT find NLOPT (missing: NLOPT_LIBRARY NLOPT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find LPSOLVE (missing: LPSOLVE_LIBRARIES LPSOLVE_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ColPack (missing: COLPACK_LIBRARIES COLPACK_LIBRARY_DIR COLPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ARPREC (missing: ARPREC_LIBRARIES ARPREC_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Linker: Default system linker
Could NOT find Ctags (missing: CTAGS_EXECUTABLE) 
Failed to locate sphinx-build executable (missing: SPHINX_EXECUTABLE) 
Failed to locate pandoc executable (missing: PANDOC_EXECUTABLE) 
===================================================================================================================
Summary of Configuration Variables
The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * Doxygen (required version >= 1.8.6)
 * OpenMP
 * Threads

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * PythonInterp

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have not been found:

 * GDB
 * CxaDemangle
 * Eigen3 (required version >= 3.1.2)
 * ViennaCL (required version >= 1.5.0)
 * rxcpp
 * TFLogger (required version >= 0.1.0)
 * BLAS
 * GLPK
 * CPLEX
 * ARPACK
 * Mosek
 * Protobuf
 * JSON (required version >= 0.11)
 * LibXml2
 * CURL
 * ZLIB
 * BZip2
 * LibLZMA
 * SNAPPY
 * LZO
 * NLopt
 * LpSolve
 * ColPack
 * ARPREC
 * Ctags
 * Sphinx
 * Pandoc
===================================================================================================================
Integrations
  OpenCV Integration is OFF      enable with -DOpenCV=ON
===================================================================================================================
Interfaces
  Python is OFF          enable with -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON
  Octave is OFF          enable with -DINTERFACE_OCTAVE=ON
  Java is OFF        enable with -DINTERFACE_JAVA=ON
  Perl is OFF        enable with -DINTERFACE_PERL=ON
  Ruby is OFF        enable with -DINTERFACE_RUBY=ON
  C# is OFF              enable with -DINTERFACE_CSHARP=ON
  R is OFF           enable with -DINTERFACE_R=ON
  Lua is OFF         enable with -DINTERFACE_LUA=ON
  Scala is OFF       enable with -DINTERFACE_SCALA=ON
===================================================================================================================
To compile shogun type
  make

To install shogun to C:/Program Files (x86)/shogun type
  make install

or to install to a custom directory
  make install DESTDIR=/my/special/path
  (or rerun cmake with -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/my/special/path) to just change the prefix
===================================================================================================================
Configuring done
```

When I build the solution generated for MSVC 2015 I have problems with eigen3. The Eigen3 has downloaded automatically but then it fails to build.
Here there is a portion of the MSVC log:

```
------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  Checking Build System
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is     -to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src/shogun/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/examples/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/examples/undocumented/libshogun    MakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/doc/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp      up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/doc/doxygen/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
------ Build started: Project: version, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
------ Build started: Project: Eigen3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
------ Build started: Project: MSDirent, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/src/shogun/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src/shogun/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
  Generating version header
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/src/shogun/CMakeLists.txt
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/src/shogun/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src/shogun/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src/shogun/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
  Creating directories for 'Eigen3'
  Creating directories for 'MSDirent'
------ Build started: Project: class_list, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/src/shogun/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src/shogun/CMakeFiles/    nerate.stamp is up-to-date.
  Generating C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/src/shogun/base/class_list.cpp
  Performing download step (git clone) for 'MSDirent'
  Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'Eigen3'
  -- Downloading...
     dst='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/third_party/Eigen3/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
     timeout='none'
  -- Using src='https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
  Cloning into 'MSDirent'...
  -- [download 1% complete]
  -- [download 100% complete]
  -- verifying file...
         file='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/third_party/Eigen3/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
  -- Downloading... done
  -- extracting...
       src='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/third_party/Eigen3/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
       dst='C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/Eigen3/src/Eigen3'
  -- extracting... [tar xfz]
  Note: checking out '8b1db5092479a73d47eafd3de739b27e876e6bf3'.

  You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
  changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
  state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

  If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
  do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

    git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

  HEAD is now at 8b1db50 Merge branch 'pfultz2-master'
  Performing update step for 'MSDirent'
  No patch step for 'MSDirent'
------ Build started: Project: rxcpp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  No configure step for 'MSDirent'
  No build step for 'MSDirent'
  Performing install step for 'MSDirent'
  -- extracting... [analysis]
  Completed 'MSDirent'
------ Build started: Project: doxygen, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  -- extracting... [rename]
  -- extracting... [clean up]
  -- extracting... done
  No update step for 'Eigen3'
  No patch step for 'Eigen3'
  Performing configure step for 'Eigen3'
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/doc/doxygen/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/doc/doxygen/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
  Generating html documentation
CUSTOMBUILD : error : tag HTML_FOOTER: footer file `C:/Users/FabrizioRiente/Desktop/shogun/doc/doxygen/pages/shogun_footer.html' does not exist
------ Skipped Build: Project: doc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
------ Skipped Build: Project: examples, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically
  -- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically - Success
  -- Standard libraries to link to explicitly: none
  -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP
  -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP - Success
  CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:370 (message):
    EIGEN_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR is deprecated.  Use INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR instead.


  -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11
  -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11 - Success
  -- Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND
  -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CXX11
  -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CXX11 - Success
  -- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
  -- A cache variable, namely BLAS_DIR, has been set to specify the install directory of BLAS
  -- Looking for BLAS -- mkl.h not found
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Looking for MKL BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Goto BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Open BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Eigen BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Eigen BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Atlas BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for PhiPACK BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for CXML BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for DXML BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for SunPerf BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for SCSL BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for SGIMATH BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for IBM ESSL BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for IBM ESSL MT BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for ACML BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for ACML BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for ACML BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Apple BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for NAS BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Generic BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Generic BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Generic BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Generic BLAS: not found
  -- Looking for Generic BLAS: not found
  CMake Warning at cmake/FindBLAS.cmake:1371 (message):
    BLA_VENDOR has been set to All but blas libraries could not be found or
    check of symbols failed.

    Please indicate where to find blas libraries.  You have three options:

    - Option 1: Provide the installation directory of BLAS library with cmake
    option: -DBLAS_DIR=your/path/to/blas

    - Option 2: Provide the directory where to find BLAS libraries with cmake
    option: -DBLAS_LIBDIR=your/path/to/blas/libs

    - Option 3: Update your environment variable (Linux: LD_LIBRARY_PATH,
    Windows: LIB, Mac: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)



    To follow libraries detection more precisely you can activate a verbose
    mode with -DBLAS_VERBOSE=ON at cmake configure.

    You could also specify a BLAS vendor to look for by setting
    -DBLA_VENDOR=blas_vendor_name.

    List of possible BLAS vendor: Goto, ATLAS PhiPACK, CXML, DXML, SunPerf,
    SCSL, SGIMATH, IBMESSL, Intel10_32 (intel mkl v10 32 bit),Intel10_64lp
    (intel mkl v10 64 bit, lp thread model, lp64 model), Intel10_64lp_seq
    (intel mkl v10 64 bit, sequential code, lp64 model),Intel( older versions
    of mkl 32 and 64 bit), ACML, ACML_MP, ACML_GPU, Apple, NAS, Generic
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    cmake/FindLAPACK.cmake:138 (find_package)
    test/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)


  -- A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
  -- LAPACK requires BLAS.
  -- Could NOT find CHOLMOD (missing: CHOLMOD_INCLUDES CHOLMOD_LIBRARIES)
  -- Could NOT find UMFPACK (missing: UMFPACK_INCLUDES UMFPACK_LIBRARIES)
  -- Could NOT find SUPERLU (missing: SUPERLU_INCLUDES SUPERLU_LIBRARIES SUPERLU_VERSION_OK)
  -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
  -- Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_SEQ_LIBRARIES BLAS_LIBRARY_DIRS)
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_c5a16"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_4f248"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_ce777"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_929b6"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_ff587"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_eb5df"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_38e76"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_d1479"
  -- Performing Test SCOTCH_Num_4
  -- Performing Test SCOTCH_Num_4 - Failed
  -- Performing Test SCOTCH_Num_8
  -- Performing Test SCOTCH_Num_8 - Failed
  -- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIB_NAMES MPI_C_HEADER_DIR MPI_C_WORKS)
  -- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES MPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR MPI_CXX_WORKS)
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_02c20"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_a0631"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_0121e"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_ad7b4"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_d372f"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_0c771"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_d56e6"
CUSTOMBUILD : CMake error : Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "devenv.com" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln" "/build" "Debug" "/project"     mTC_3509b"
  -- Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing: MPI_Fortran_LIB_NAMES MPI_Fortran_F77_HEADER_DIR MPI_Fortran_MODULE_DIR MPI_Fortran_WORKS)
  -- Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND MPI_Fortran_FOUND)
  -- Performing Test PTSCOTCH_Num_4
  -- Performing Test PTSCOTCH_Num_4 - Failed
  -- Performing Test PTSCOTCH_Num_8
  -- Performing Test PTSCOTCH_Num_8 - Failed
  -- A version of Pastix has been found but pastix_nompi.h does not exist in the include directory. Because Eigen tests require a version without MPI,      disable the Pastix backend.
  -- Could NOT find SPQR (missing: SPQR_INCLUDES SPQR_LIBRARIES)
  -- Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND
  -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_FASTMATH
  -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_FASTMATH - Failed
  -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_FPFAST
  -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_FPFAST - Success
  -- Boost version: 1.65.0
  -- Could NOT find GOOGLEHASH (missing: GOOGLEHASH_INCLUDES GOOGLEHASH_COMPILE)
  -- Could NOT find ADOLC (missing: ADOLC_INCLUDES ADOLC_LIBRARIES)
  -- Could NOT find MPFR (missing: MPFR_INCLUDES MPFR_LIBRARIES MPFR_VERSION_OK) (Required is at least version "2.3.0")
  -- Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_INCLUDES GMP_LIBRARIES)
  -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
  -- Could NOT find FFTW (missing: FFTW_INCLUDES FFTW_LIBRARIES)
  -- Found OpenGL: opengl32
  -- Could NOT find GLUT (missing: GLUT_glut_LIBRARY GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR)
  CMake Warning (dev) at unsupported/test/CMakeLists.txt:121 (if):
    Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
    keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
    details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
    warning.

    Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
    is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
  This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
  -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version     .0")
  -- Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND
  -- Qt4 not found, so disabling the mandelbrot and opengl demos
  -- ************************************************************
  -- ***    Eigen's unit tests configuration summary          ***
  -- ************************************************************
  --
  -- Build type:        Release
  -- Build site:        desktop-t00380c
  -- Build string:      unknownwin-19.0.24215.1-32bit
  -- Enabled backends:  Boost.Multiprecision,
  -- Disabled backends: Cholmod,  UmfPack,  SuperLU,  PaStiX,  METIS,  SPQR,  Qt4 support,  GoogleHash,  Adolc,  MPFR C++,  fftw,  OpenGL,
  -- Default order:     Column-major
  -- Maximal matrix/vector size: 320
  -- SSE2:              Using architecture defaults
  -- SSE3:              Using architecture defaults
  -- SSSE3:             Using architecture defaults
  -- SSE4.1:            Using architecture defaults
  -- SSE4.2:            Using architecture defaults
  -- AVX:               Using architecture defaults
  -- FMA:               Using architecture defaults
  -- AVX512:            Using architecture defaults
  -- Altivec:           Using architecture defaults
  -- VSX:               Using architecture defaults
  -- ARM NEON:          Using architecture defaults
  -- ARMv8 NEON:        Using architecture defaults
  -- S390X ZVECTOR:     Using architecture defaults
  -- C++11:             OFF
  -- SYCL:              OFF
  -- CUDA:              OFF
  --
  CXX:               C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
   CXX_FLAGS:           /EHsc /wd4127 /wd4505 /wd4714 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
   Sparse lib flags:

  -- ************************************************************
  --
  -- Configured Eigen 3.3.4
  --
  -- To build/run the unit tests, read this page:
  --   http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tests
  --
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/Eigen3/src/Eigen3-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/shogun/build/Eigen3/src/Eigen3-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
```

By looking at the CMakeError.log the error seems related to Eigen that tries to include `pthread.h`

```
Build started 3/25/2018 12:13:00 PM.
Project "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1f42b.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\".
  Creating directory "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".
  Creating directory "cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\cmTC_1f42b.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\cmTC_1f42b.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /    GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue     "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"
  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /    Fo"cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_1f42b.dir\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\Fabrizio     Riente\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"

  CheckIncludeFile.c
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include     file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1f42b.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\shogun\build\Eigen3\src\Eigen3-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_1f42b.vcxproj" (default targets) --     FAILED.
```

Someone can help me solving this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I think the missing `pthread.h` was just from a try-compilation, i.e., to check whether that file is available. Overall, I'd suggest filing an issue to the shugun developers. Or, if you think the shogun-scripts are working properly, to the Eigen-developers (in that case, with an example that does not use the shogun install-scripts).

Comment: The problem appears only with the 32bit build. I submitted an issue to the shogun developers